# How do I convert a wave file to a 128x128 spectogram? I am trying to create a dataset from audio from 2 folders: cat audio( label 1)/dog audio(2)

Tags: python, neural-network, wav

#This code searches for 128x128 but does not convert audio to 128x128

for x in range(40):

```
y, sr = librosa.load('C:/audio files/folderCat/'  + str(x)+'.wav',   
duration=2.97)  
ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
if ps.shape != (128, 128): continue
D.append( (ps, 1) )
```

for x in range(40):

```
y, sr = librosa.load('C:/audio files/folderDog' +    
str(x)+'.wav', duration=2.97)  
ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
if ps.shape != (128, 128): continue
D.append( (ps, 2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer. By default ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr) creates a spectogram of 128 on the y axis but the x axis needs to be adjusted in order to have 128 there. You need to adjust the duration so that when divided by 23 milliseconds you receive 128.  So I would need the duration to equal approximately 2.95 seconds or 2,950 miliseconds.